# Syncfusion chart question

Tags: c#, winforms, syncfusion

I'm using Visual Studio 2008, SyncFusion Essential Studio Enterprise Edition, (WinForms) version 7.203.0.20.

I was wondering if anyone can help me out on a small question: how can I specify a custom color for each line in my line chart?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To set color for line chart:

`this.chartControl1.Series[0].Style.Interior = new BrushInfo(GradientStyle.Vertical, Color.Red, Color.Orange);`

Here is a help link - 
http://www.syncfusion.com/support/kb/83/How-do-I-set-the-Interior-colors-for-the-chart-series-data-points

If you want individual connecting lines to be of different color, then you need to handle the ChartSeries.PrepareStyle event as below:

`this.chartControl1.Series[0].PrepareStyle += new ChartPrepareStyleInfoHandler(series_PrepareStyle);`

void series_PrepareStyle(object sender, ChartPrepareStyleInfoEventArgs args)
        {
            //Specifying  different Colors for data points using Prepare style event
            ChartSeries series = sender as ChartSeries;
            if (series != null)
            {
                if (this.chartControl1.Series[0].Type.ToString() == "Line")
                {
                    if (args.Index == 0)
                        args.Style.Interior = new Syncfusion.Drawing.BrushInfo(Color.Red);
                    else if (args.Index == 1)
                        args.Style.Interior = new Syncfusion.Drawing.BrushInfo(Color.Green);
                    else if (args.Index == 2)
                        args.Style.Interior = new Syncfusion.Drawing.BrushInfo(Color.Blue);
                    else if (args.Index == 3)
                        args.Style.Interior = new Syncfusion.Drawing.BrushInfo(Color.Yellow);
                    else if (args.Index == 4)

http://samples.syncfusion.com/sfwinsamples82/Chart.Windows/Chart%20Types/Line%20Charts/Sample.aspx?args=1

Regards,
Jay